# merging redundant tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed while browsing tags that there are several duplicates, either due to transliteration differences (e.g. kadish/kaddish) or to phrasing (e.g. t'filah/prayer).  Is there a way to review and merge such tags?

Edit: links to some redundant tags (apparently I don't know how to edit this wiki yet; sorry about half the links being broken but with luck the URLs suffice):

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka - 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanukah

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men - 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-male

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pesach-passover - 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover-seder-hagada

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanach -
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanach-scripture-bible

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer - 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tefila-davening-prayer

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzitzis - 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzitzits

(I was mistaken about kadish/kaddish, apparently.  Oops.)

Not actually redundant but looked like it from the names (maybe the first should be clarified?):
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shemos -
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shemot-exodus

Comment: Also see: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68/using-tags-synonyms-instead-of-long-names

Comment: I've merged all of the ones identified in the question except Pesach-Passover and Passover-Seder-Hagada , since the latter refers to something more specific than the former. I renamed shemos to shemos-sacred-names for clarity. Thanks for the spadework!

Comment: @Isaac, did you not leave the original tags as synonyms...?

Comment: @AviD I guess old habits (and paradigms) die hard. I'll get the hang of this synonyms business in due course.

Comment: @Isaac :) they are immensely useful - especially here, where there are multiple ways to write a single concept...

Comment: Speaking of spadework, perhaps merge `agriculture`, `plants`, `botany`, and `trees`? @IsaacMoses

Comment: ...or at least the first three of those.

Comment: @msh210 merged and synonymed the first three.

Comment: Can a Mod please merge Musar into Mussar? I created it not realizing Mussar existed.

Comment: @SethJ, I don't think anybody but me saw your comment and I'm not a mod.  You might want to post that as a new question on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way:

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

However, I can't seem to seem to find those specific tags you mentioned as being duplicates. Can you link to the tags that are duplicates. A mod can then come around and make the proper changes...

Thanks

Comment: Ah, you cant find them because @Isaac already merged them - see comment on question... :)

Comment: @AviD, actually his question is what prompted me to add the links to the post.

Comment: @avid yep, note the timestamps of the edits.

Comment: heh, oops... well then, +1 ;)